# How to exclude from commits but not delete?

Tags: git

I have a repository that has already been some files. I want to modify them locally but not commit. I don't want to delete them. I want to freeze them,  how to do it?

Comment: Please elaborate more!

Comment: Search for "ignore" (.gitignore)

Comment: `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` would also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instruct Git to ignore changes to a tracked file like this:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged [filename]
```

If you want Git to start taking notice of changes to that file again, you can use:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged [filename]
```

One thing to be aware of with this technique. I don't think that files marked in this way are protected during a `git pull` or similar operation - I think they'll be overwritten. I'm not 100% sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in your repository named `.gitignore` git will use its rules when looking at files to commit.

**Example .gitignore.**

```
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db
```

Comment: If the files are already being tracked in the repository, adding them to the `.gitignore` file won't have any effect.

Comment: Git lets you ignore those files by assuming they are unchanged. This is done by running the git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/file.txt command. Once marking a file as such, git will completely ignore any changes on that file; they will not show up when running git status or git diff, nor will they ever be committed.